# kube-apiserver started to die on start-up after a few months of good work - how can I check its logs?

Tags: logging, kubernetes, kubeadm

The stage: a control plane machine, kubernetes 1.24.3 on a baremetal Ubuntu 22.04, installed with kubeadm, there is also one worker node. The whole set-up worked like a charm for 4 months until some unknown silent kaboom yesterday (I actually don't exclude a sudden hardware issue)

The problem: port 6443 is listed by netstat for the first few minutes after the control plane machine start-up, and then disappears. While it's on, the apiserver is irresponsive anyway - any connection attempt to it is reset by the peer. I.e. there should be some serious problems on the kube-apiserver side, but I can't figure out what it's unhappy with.

I checked some obvious things - ip address didn't change, enough disk space, k8s' certificates are not expired. So I need to check `kube-apiserver` logs somehow.

As for the logs, the official page [says](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/#looking-at-logs):

> On systemd-based systems, you may need to use journalctl instead of
> examining log files.

But... what component should I run journalctl for?? If I run it for kubelet (`journalctl -u kubelet`), I don't see much of the logs related to apiserver apart from "can't connect to :6443"

And I don't see any service named `kube-apiserver` or alike when I run e.g. just `systemctl`... Also, there are no logs in `/var/log/` (not surprising since it's a systemd-based system, but I checked nevertheless)

I wonder is there a way to check the apiserver's logs, or is there some gotcha that I'm missing? Would appreciate any help on this subject!

Comment: @larsks uhhuh! I use containerd, so got it... that's a good lead, thanks. I will try it on Monday, will write the result down here. Thanks!

Comment: @larsks You were absolutely right. Looking into pod logs on the control plane helped.
TL/DR: etcd data corruption

So logs for a pod with kube-apiserver I saw this:
"transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused"

2379 turns out to be an ETCD port, and its pod log is showing this:
"error":"walpb: crc mismatch". 

There is enough disk space. Might be a bug somewhere, but probably a HW issue, as noticed e.g. here:
https://groups.google.com/g/coreos-dev/c/fRm2o58_N1U?pli=1
As I understand, I can't recover the etcd, so reinstall it is.

Comment: @larsks if you put what you already wrote as an answer, I'll be happy to mark it as an accepted one. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped! I've moved my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my clusters, kube-apiserver runs in a pod (and logs are available via kubectl logs).

If the apiserver was down, I would log into a node directly and use the container runtime to examine the container logs (e.g., crictl logs or docker logs or whatever is appropriate for your system).

For example:

```
# Find the kube-apiserver pod
root@infra-control-plane:/# crictl pods | grep kube-apiserver
ca01411d447a6       3 days ago          Ready               kube-apiserver-infra-control-plane                  kube-system          0                   (default)
```

```
# Find container in that pod
root@infra-control-plane:/# crictl ps --pod ca01411d447a6
CONTAINER           IMAGE               CREATED             STATE               NAME                ATTEMPT             POD ID              POD
44da6bf198244       400e6a4878256       3 days ago          Running             kube-apiserver      0                   ca01411d447a6       kube-apiserver-infra-control-plane
```

```
# Look at logs for that container
root@infra-control-plane:/# crictl logs 44da6bf198244 |& tail -2
Trace[1944612718]: ---"Writing http response done" 1254ms (21:59:45.444)
Trace[1944612718]: [1.255113794s] [1.255113794s] END
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks @larsks ! Like I wrote, that's exactly what helped. Cheers!